# Finding 'lakes' (enclosed 0s) in a grid?

Tags: algorithm

So recently I've learning BFS and DFS and their applications. Once common application is finding the islands in a grid. I've got that working and understand how it works. However, I've meth a scenerio which is quite mind boggling. That is, how would one find a lake within an island? For example:

```
00000000000
00111111000
01110011100
01100000110
01110011100
01111111100
00000000000
```

The 0s surrounding the 1s can be classified as the sea.

```
    00000000000
    00111111000
    01110011100
    01100000000
    01110011100
    01111111100
    00000000000
```

In the example above there is no lake, unlike the first grid.

What I'm currently doing is using DFS/BFS to find all connected 0s. Verifying that theses 0s are surrounded by ones has become quite problematic. Could I get a bit of guidance on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A connected component of zeroes is not a lake when for one of its cells, this holds:

- the cell is on the first column
- the cell is on the first row
- the cell is on the last column
- the cell is on the last row.

Perform a DFS/BFS from all cells on the first/last rows/columns. By definition, the rest of the unvisited cells must belong to a lake.

Comment: I've improved the question to clarify a few things.

Comment: What of a case where there is more than one island?

Answer (score 0):

This code get you the lakes and their coordinates in this format:

```
{x: '', y: '', coords: {top: '', right: '', bottom: '', left: ''}}
```

Which coords are coordinates of `1` arround this `0`;

I just solve it with this code for **fun**. But It is true!

```js
var input = `00000000000\n00111111000\n01110011100\n01100000110\n01110011100\n01111111100\n00000000000`,
  input2 = `00000000000\n00111111000\n01110011100\n01100000000\n01110011100\n01111111100\n00000000000`;

function hasLeft1(arr, x, y) {
  if (y == 0) {
    return -1;
  }
  for (var i = y - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    if (arr[x][i] == "1" || arr[x][i] == 1) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

function hasRight1(arr, x, y) {
  if (y == arr[x].length - 1) {
    return -1;
  }
  for (var i = y + 1; i < arr[x].length; i++) {
    if (arr[x][i] == "1" || arr[x][i] == 1) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

function hasTop1(arr, x, y) {
  if (x == 0) {
    return -1;
  }
  for (var i = x - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    if (arr[i][y] == "1" || arr[i][y] == 1) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

function hasBottom1(arr, x, y) {
  if (x == arr.length - 1) {
    return -1;
  }
  for (var i = x + 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i][y] == "1" || arr[i][y] == 1) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

function findLakeZeros(arr) {
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      if (arr[i][j] == "0") {
        var obj = {
          left: hasLeft1(arr, i, j),
          top: hasTop1(arr, i, j),
          right: hasRight1(arr, i, j),
          bottom: hasBottom1(arr, i, j)
        };
        if (
          obj.top != -1 &&
          obj.right != -1 &&
          obj.bottom != -1 &&
          obj.left != -1
        )
          output.push({
            num: output.length,
            x: i,
            y: j,
            coords: obj
          });
      }
    }
  }
  return output;
}

function inRowZeros(z1, z2) {
  if (
    z1.x == z2.x &&
    z1.coords.left == z2.coords.left &&
    z1.coords.right == z2.coords.right
  ) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function inColumnZeros(z1, z2) {
  if (
    z1.y == z2.y &&
    z1.coords.top == z2.coords.top &&
    z1.coords.bottom == z2.coords.bottom
  ) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function belongTo(arr, zero) {
  var keys = Object.keys(arr);
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[keys[i]].length; j++) {
      if (
        arr[keys[i]][j].x == zero.x &&
        arr[keys[i]][j].y == zero.y &&
        arr[keys[i]][j].coords.top == zero.coords.top &&
        arr[keys[i]][j].coords.right == zero.coords.right &&
        arr[keys[i]][j].coords.bottom == zero.coords.bottom &&
        arr[keys[i]][j].coords.left == zero.coords.left
      ) {
        return keys[i];
      }
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

function mergeZeros(arr) {
  var obj = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (inColumnZeros(arr[i], arr[j])) {
        var itm = belongTo(obj, arr[i]),
          itm2 = belongTo(obj, arr[j]);
        if (itm != -1) {
          obj[itm].push(arr[j]);
        } else if (itm2 != -1) {
          obj[itm2].push(arr[i]);
        } else {
          obj[arr[i].num] = [];
          obj[arr[i].num].push(arr[i]);
          obj[arr[i].num].push(arr[j]);
        }
      } else if (inRowZeros(arr[i], arr[j])) {
        var itm = belongTo(obj, arr[i]),
          itm2 = belongTo(obj, arr[j]);
        if (itm != -1) {
          obj[itm].push(arr[j]);
        } else if (itm2 != -1) {
          obj[itm2].push(arr[i]);
        } else {
          obj[arr[i].num] = [];
          obj[arr[i].num].push(arr[i]);
          obj[arr[i].num].push(arr[j]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return obj;
}

function unique(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (arr[i].num == arr[j].num) {
        arr.splice(j, 1);
        i--;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

function areNighbour(z1, z2) {
  if (z1.x == z2.x && Math.abs(z1.y - z2.y) == 1) {
    return true;
  }
  if (z1.y == z2.y && Math.abs(z1.x - z2.x) == 1) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function validLake(arr) {
  var rows = [];
  var cols = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    rows.push(arr[i].x);
    cols.push(arr[i].y);
  }
  rows.sort();
  cols.sort();
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length - 1; i++) {
    if (rows[i] == rows[i + 1]) {
      continue;
    } else if (rows[i] != rows[i + 1] - 1) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < cols.length - 1; i++) {
    if (cols[i] == cols[i + 1]) {
      continue;
    } else if (cols[i] != cols[i + 1] - 1) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function starter(input) {
  var zeros = findLakeZeros(input.split("\n"));

  var result = mergeZeros(zeros);

  var oo = Object.keys(result);

  for (var i = 0; i < oo.length; i++) {
    var un = unique(result[oo[i]]);
    if (validLake(un)) {
      console.log("These zeros are create a lake: ", un);
    }
  }
}

starter(input);
console.log("--------------example 2-------------");
starter(input2);
```